# Impress won't save bullets or spacing

Tags: formatting, libreoffice, text-formatting, libreoffice-impress

I make a nice neat Libre'Office Impress document.

I put paragraphs on the page, with a quarter inch spacing after them.

While I am working with the document, all is well.

I then save the document in microsoft powerpoint format

When I reopen the file, all such formatting is lost.

Is this a bug or a feature ?

This behavior was observed in Version: 4.3.3.2

Here are two screen caps of before and after I save, close, and reopen the file.

The big "LIAR !!!" box was added to the screen cap on the re-opened file.

[image: Before Saving and Closing]

[image: After Re-Opening]

Answer (score 0):

In Impress, LibreOffice v. 4.4.3.2, saving line-spacing in a PPT-formatted file worked when I used the *Line Spacing* tool icon:
[image: Impress document saved in PPT format]
Perhaps the method you're using to add line spacing is not compatible with the PPT format, rather than native ODP format, but the *Line Spacing* tool format is maintained.

Also, you've not mentioned the *version* of LibreOffice; behavior could be different in other versions or other OS (my test was made on a Windows PC).

Comment: Version: 4.3.3.2

Comment: I do not have that drop down lits that you have on yours, i.e., the seventh item

Comment: Perhaps that is only available in the current version, 4.4.3.2, so update LibreOffice -- the price is reasonable ;)